# Ошибка при спользовании nonlocal

Tags: python

```
question1 = False


@bot.message_handler(commands=['begin'])
def f_question1(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Ok! Let's start!")
    bot.reply_to(message, "What is the position of the person to whom the statement is addressed?")
    nonlocal question1
    question1 = True
```

Ошибка в строке "nonlocal question1".
Текст ошибки: SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'question1' found
Может я не правильно понимаю принцип работы nonlocal или просто невнимательный. Но я же создя перменую question1 во внешнем scope относительно функции.

Comment: Чем global не угодил?

Comment: Не очень разобрался что когда нужно использовать. Разве global не создает новую перменную но во внешнем scope, а nonlocal говорит искать переменную с этим именем во внешнем scope?

Comment: Нет, global ничего не создаёт

Comment: @CheshireCat https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261961

Comment: Огромное спасбо! Помогли разобраться что к чему.

Answer (score 3):

`nonlocal` нужен для случаев с замыканиями. Например:

```
In [20]: def foo():
    ...:     var = 5
    ...:     def bar():
    ...:         nonlocal var
    ...:         var = 6
    ...:     bar()
    ...:     return var
    ...:

In [21]: foo()
Out[21]: 6
```

Как видите, мы изменили значения переменной ну уровень выше функции `bar`. Функция бар "замкнула" в тебе переменную. Если хотите более детально разобраться в замыканиях, изучите тему декораторов.

`global` нужен для изменения глобальных переменных (определены на уровне модуля), например:

```
In [23]: def foo():
    ...:     global var
    ...:     var = 11
    ...:     return var
    ...:

In [24]: foo()
Out[24]: 11
```

Как видите, изменилась переменная на. уровне модуля.

Вот наглядный пример одновременного использования `nonlocal` & `global`:

```
In [28]: var = 10

In [29]: def foo():
    ...:     var = 11
    ...:     def bar():
    ...:         nonlocal var
    ...:         var = 100
    ...:     bar()
    ...:     return var
    ...:

In [30]: foo()
Out[30]: 100

In [31]: var
Out[31]: 10
```

Как видите, глобальная `var` не изменила свое значения, в то время как внутренняя `var` изменилась. `nonlocal` никак не влияет на глобальные переменные.

Вот небольшая визуализация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Использовать `global` не рекомендуется.**